# MPLABX v4.01 (Linux) cannot find PICKit3

Tags: mplabx, pickit

I just bought a PICKit3 and Linux finds it:

```
$ lsusb
...

Bus 003 Device 081: ID 04d8:900a Microchip Technology, Inc. PICkit3
```

But MPLABX doesn't recognize it (see image, the SN-foldout is unavailable). I just re-installed v4.01 but the issue remains. I tried run MPLAB as root to see if it was a permission issue, but the error is for root as well.

I tried MPLABX under Windows, and it recognized the PICKit3 immediately. I am not, however, going to develop things under Windows.

Does the Linux-version of MPLABX require some special configuration? I am running 64-bit Debian 7.3 (according to /etc/debian_version).

[image]

Comment: I had no problems using it in Linux. I see that reinstalling doesn't help - so you might need to go to Microchip support.

Comment: ..."I just re-installed v4.01 but the issue remains."

Comment: Yes, I saw that and edited my comment.

Comment: I've had no trouble with it, either, using Ubuntu 16.04.  Which distribution are you running?

Comment: I am running Debian 7.3 (adding this info to the OP as well).

Comment: Did you add the appropriate udev rules so that it can be accessed by user processes?

Comment: Now that you mention it, there was a note during the installation saying that udev-rules were changed, and some systems requires a reboot for them to work. I have not tried rebooting, will do.

Comment: No rebooting required. You can reload the rules with udevadm: "udevadm control --reload"

Comment: Neither a reboot not a --reload solved the problem.

I am now contacting Microchip support to see if they can shine some light on this.

Comment: Why do you install v 4.01, while latest Linux version are 4.20? Have you tried installing latest version? It should be backwards compatible with projects created in previous version. At least as long as the major version (4) matches.
Also check for the *mchp_tools.rules file in your /etc/udev/rules.d directory. Probably it wasn't installed for some reason even if installer claimed it did.

Comment: @nstorm: this thread is from 2017.

Comment: @bos doh! Didn't noticed that because it was bumped to the top by recent answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was using a too old glibc-version for the MPLABCOMM-libs. Upgrading the glibc solved everything.

Comment: wow, im really surprised that you got it working under Linux. Did you buy the XC8 compiler for linux as well?

Comment: No, I use the free version.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I updated glibc-xxx, but the problem still persists.
Now i'm trying with this way, from microchipdeveloper.com mplabx:installation#step9

For Linux distributions that use systemd, the systemd-udevd unit may be setup to avoid inter-process communications via sockets for security reasons. Recently Ubuntu 18.04LTS has been shipped in this way. This is a change from 17.10. Other distributions like Manjaro are also shipped with blocked inter--process communications via systemd. MPLAB X IPE and IDE rely on the systemd--udevd unit for plug and play. MPLAB X software has udev rules that allow a program to run on plug-and-play notifications. This program relies on sockets to communicate with MPLAB X IDE and IPE. So, to have working plug-and-play in MPLAB X software, you need to re-enable socket communications.

You can do this by adding an override file for systemd-udevd.
​

```
$ sudo systemctl edit systemd-udevd
```

This will open an editor and will create an override.conf file. In the override file, include the following lines:
​

```
[Service]

IPAddressAllow=localhost
```

Then re-start the service:
​

```
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Finally check the override.conf has been loaded:
​

```
$ sudo systemctl status systemd-udevd

● systemd-udevd.service - udev Kernel Device Manager
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-udevd.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/systemd-udevd.service.d
           └─override.conf
```

> IN MY CASE :

```
systemd-udevd.service - udev Kernel Device Manager   
> Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-udevd.service; static;
> vendor preset: disabled)
```

> 

```
jul 11 22:00:53 localhost.localdomain systemd-udevd[2757]: Process
> '/etc/.mplab_ide/mchplinusbdevice add' failed with exit code 250.
```

Comment: Hi - Thanks for this info. It's not clear to me *exactly* what you mean by "*Now i'm trying whint this way*". At the end of the text you copied from http://microchipdeveloper.com/mplabx:installation#step9 (some of which is unfortunately incomplete and needs fixing) you *seem* to be reporting an error message. So my questions are: (a) Have you actually *successfully* followed those steps and this is an *answer*? (In which case, why are you reporting an error?) Or do you have problems, and this is a *question* that's in the wrong place? (b) Will you be fixing the problems with the copied text?

Comment: Hi,
 (a) The PICKIT3 is completely functional following those steps. 
 (b) the reporting error message still persist, but not seem affect the pickit3 functions.